# JSTL for each tag unit test

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to display a map on UI. For that I need to iterate through the loop to get all values of my map. Is there any way I can display the map without using JSTL for each tag? . If JSTL is the only way, Is there anyway to unit test the for each loop of JSTL tag?

Comment: Have you heard of scriplets? (Although I'd definitely prefer JSTL.)

Comment: Yeah. But is there an way to unit test the scriptlets in Jsp?